# Major and minor tickmarks with plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I would like to generate a figure in `plotly` like the following figure generated with the base R graphics:

[image: R figure with minor ticks]

The R code for the figure above is the following:

```
x = c(1,2,3,4,5)
y = c(0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000)
axseq = y
plot(x, log10(y), yaxt="n")
axis(2, at=log10(axseq), labels=as.character(axseq))
for (i in 1:5){
    bb = 1:10; a = (bb*10^(i-2));   axis(2, at=log10(a), tcl=-0.25, labels=F)
}
```

My `plotly`code for the same figure so far is the following:

```
p = plot_ly(x=x, y=log10(y), mode="markers") %>%
layout(yaxis = list(tickmode="array", tickvals=log10(axseq), ticktext=as.character(axseq), zeroline=F, showline=T, ticks="outside"),
       xaxis = list(showline=T, ticks="outside"))
```

it has the major ticks, but I can't find how to add the minor ticks on the y axis.

Answer (score 7):

As you started to implement already, you can customize the ticks by specifying the values at which they are placed (with `tickvals`) and the labels (with `ticktext`).  But you need to put a value for every tick location in `tickvals`, and every `tickval` needs a corresponding `ticktext`.  So, the way to differentiate between major and minor ticks is by setting the ticktext to an empty string for all the minor ticks (because plotly doen't have a way to specify minor ticks *per se*).

```
tval <- sort(as.vector(sapply(seq(1,9), function(x) x*10^seq(-1,3)))) #generates a sequence of numbers in logarithmic divisions
ttxt <- rep("",length(tval))  # no label at most of the ticks
ttxt[seq(1,37,9)] <- as.character(tval)[seq(1,37,9)] # every 9th tick is labelled

p = plot_ly(x=x, y=y, mode="markers") %>%
  layout(yaxis = list(type="log",
                      zeroline=F, showline=T, 
                      ticks="outside",
                      tickvals=tval,
                      ticktext=ttxt),
         xaxis = list(showline=T, ticks="outside"))
p
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's very close to what I'm looking for, but there is an important detail missing: the minor ticks should be shorter than the major ticks. I should be able to control the tick length with the `ticklen` attribute, but I don't think I can control the length of the major and minor ticks separately.

Comment: No `ticklen` only takes a single value. You can't set them differently

Comment: I'm working on using your answer dww. Now hoping to find a way to only show gridlines at the labeled ticks

Comment: @Mark I have a solution, but its too much for a comment.  Suggest asking a new question and linking to this one.  If you let me know about the new question (via a comment here), I can answer it for you.

Comment: @dww i posted it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54612142/reduce-number-of-gridlines-in-plotly-scatter-plots-with-log-scale-in-r-shiny

Answer (score 5):

I found a solution by adding a trace which is not visible and a second y axis, it's a bit of a hack, but it works:

```
library(plotly)
x = c(1,2,3,4,5)
y = c(0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000)
axseq = y

minTickLoc = numeric()
    for (i in 1:5){
    bb = 1:10;
    minTickLoc = c(minTickLoc, (bb*10^(i-2)))
}


p = plot_ly(x=x, y=y, mode="markers", marker=list(opacity=0), showlegend=F) %>%    
   add_trace(x=x, y=y, mode="markers", yaxis="y2", 
             marker = list(color="black")) %>%
   layout(yaxis = list(type = "log", tickvals = axseq, 
                       ticktext = as.character(axseq), 
                       zeroline=F, showline=T, ticks="outside", 
                       ticklen=8, showgrid=T),
          yaxis2 = list(type="log", tickvals=minTickLoc, 
                        ticktext=rep("", length(minTickLoc)), 
                        zeroline=F, showline=F, ticks="outside", 
                        ticklen=3, showgrid=T),
          xaxis = list(showline=T, ticks="outside", ticklen=8))
```

[image]