# Set major tick labels to be displayed as scientific notation in a Plotly plot in R

Tags: r, plotly, scientific-notation

I'm trying to get `plotly` to put values in scientific notation regardless of their size, i.e. 100 should be 1E02 in the ticks, but it keeps showing numbers below 10.000 as normal annotation.

Setting the format is done through `exponentformat = "E"`"but it only affects larger numbers.

Here is an example code of how I write it:

```
f2 <- list(family = "Old Standard TT, serif", size = 14, color = "black")

ax <- list(showticklabels = TRUE, tickfont = f2,  showgrid=F,  zeroline=T,  showline=T,  nticks = 4,  exponentformat = "E")
ay <- list(nticks = 4,  showticklabels = TRUE,  tickfont = f2,  showgrid=F,  zeroline=T,  showline=T,  range =c(0,max(mtcars$disp*1.2)),  exponentformat = "E")

plot_ly(x = mtcars$mpg  , y = mtcars$disp) %>%
  add_trace(type = 'scatter', mode = 'markers', 
            marker = list(color = c('black'))) %>%
  add_lines(hoverinfo='none', line = list(color = 'black')) %>%
  layout(title = 'A plot in science',yaxis = ay, xaxis = ax,
         showlegend = FALSE, hovermode = "y")
```

manipulating the values to be in the 10k plus range gives the desired output though:

```
 mtcars$disp <- mtcars$disp *100
```

Comment: How about `mtcars$disp <- format(mtcars$disp, scientific=T)`?

Comment: I don't think that will help, it should probably be changed in the `layout` or `label` of the plot.

Comment: It seems to do really weird things to my data in a multipanel plot. The data plotted is different lines and the range argument fails as well when I apply the format approach

Comment: might be easier with `ggplot2` and `ggplotly`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's just do it ourselves in JavaScript, if Plotly doesn't provide the needed functionality.

- let's grab all ticks on the y-axis using d3

  ```
  ticks = Plotly.d3.selectAll('g.ytick');
  ```
- the raw data is stored in `data.x`
- then change the representation of each one to scientific notation

  ```
  Plotly.d3
        .selectAll('g.ytick')
        .each(function(data, i) 
          {
             Plotly.d3.select(this)
                      .select('text')
                      .html(formatNumber(data.x, 2));
          })
  ```

  - finally inject all the code using `htmlwidgets` in our graph

    p <- onRender(p, javascript)
- now it would be one-time only change, every time a user zooms or modifies the plot the changes would be lost. In order to make sure that changes are applied every time the code is wrapped in a function `fix_ticks()` and added to Plotly's [`plotly_afterplot`](https://plot.ly/javascript/plotlyjs-events/#afterplot-event) event (`el` is the `htmlwidget` element)

  ```
  el.on('plotly_afterplot', fix_ticks);
  ```

---

**Update**

If you want to change the format of the scientific notation, you could write your function, e.g.

```
function formatNumber(num, desiredLength)
{
  num = num.toExponential().toUpperCase();
  var r = /(\\d*)([E][-+])(\\d*)/;
  var fields = r.exec(num);
  if (fields !== null && fields.length > 3)
  {
    return fields[1] + fields[2] + fields[3].padStart(desiredLength, '0');
  }
  else
  {
    return num;
  }   
}
```

and then call it for each tick

```
ticks.forEach(function(tick) 
{
  var num = parseInt(tick[0].innerHTML); 
  tick[0].innerHTML = formatNumber(num, 2);
})
```

Note: this might not work in RStudio but shows up correctly in your browser after saving the output.

---

**Complete code**

```
library(plotly)
library(htmlwidgets)

p <- plot_ly(x = mtcars$mpg  , y = mtcars$disp) %>%
  add_lines()

javascript <- "
function(el, x) 
{
  function fixTicks()
  {

    Plotly.d3
          .selectAll('g.ytick')
          .each(function(data, i) 
            {
               Plotly.d3.select(this)
                        .select('text')
                        .html(formatNumber(data.x, 2));
            }) 
  }

  function formatNumber(num, desiredLength)
  {
    num = num.toExponential().toUpperCase();
    var r = /(\\d*)([E][-+])(\\d*)/;
    var fields = r.exec(num);
    if (fields !== null && fields.length > 3)
    {
      return fields[1] + fields[2] + fields[3].padStart(desiredLength, '0');
    }
    else
    {
      return num;
    }
  }

  el.on('plotly_afterplot', fixTicks);
}"

p <- onRender(p, javascript)  
p
```

Comment: Hey max thanks for another great solution again. 2 things; can this be adjusted so that the exponentials shows 1 or 2 decimals?

Comment: The second is: I tried to apply this to a subplot structure, both applying onrender on each subplot and on the overall plot, but in the best case it only affected the first panel. I will post a new question for this

Comment: this code does fascinating things to Plotly's ticks that show up as 10k and 20k etc haha. See comment other question as well. It turns them into 1.00E1 understandably.

Comment: Max, one more little thing, I'm finally getting back around to this issue. Can you show how to apply this to both x and y axes in one go?

Comment: @Maximillian, thanks. There is one more obstacle I just discovered, the current answer in combination with plotly's layout(p, yaxis = list(type = 'log')) creates a horrible mess. Should I write another question for this specific scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Particularly aimed at plots where log scale is used (which seems to cause problems with the current javascript solution), I found another solution without using `javascript`. It works based on making a list of tickvalues and one of text labels at the whole exponent numbers and leaving the rest empty, and then inserting the two into the plot through the `layout` arguments for `tickvals` and `ticktext` arguments

depending on whether it is a regular `scatter` or `scatter3d` the layout code changes a bit, but the principle is the same.

In `scatter3d` the axes are set within the `scene = list()` argument. in `scatter` it is done directly in `layout()`. `camera`, `autosize` etc are arguments used to make the plots nice and square, and for 3D at the right zoom level, and of a fixed size.

The answer is based on another SO post found: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38064857/6356210)

```
    library(shiny)
    library(plotly)

    shinyApp(
      ui = fluidPage( plotlyOutput('plot') ),

      server = function(input, output) {
        output$plot <- renderPlotly ({

          mtcars <- rbind(mtcars, mtcars*1000, mtcars/1000)  #create data with big logarithmic range
          maxlog <- round(log10(max(mtcars[['mpg']][mtcars[['mpg']]>0], mtcars[['disp']][mtcars[['disp']]>0],mtcars[['cyl']][mtcars[['cyl']]>0])), digits = 0) +1 # determine max log needed
          minlog <- round(log10(min(mtcars[['mpg']][mtcars[['mpg']]>0], mtcars[['disp']][mtcars[['disp']]>0],mtcars[['cyl']][mtcars[['cyl']]>0])), digits = 0) -1 # determine min log needed
          logrange <- (maxlog - minlog)*9 +1 # get the distance between smallest and largest log power
          tval <- sort(as.vector(sapply(seq(1,9), function(x) x*10^seq(minlog, maxlog)))) #generates a sequence of numbers in logarithmic divisions
          ttxt <- rep("",length(tval))  # no label at most of the ticks
          ttxt[seq(1,logrange,9)] <- formatC(tval, format = "e", digits = 2)[seq(1,logrange,9)] # every 9th tick is labelled


          p <- plot_ly(source = 'ThresholdScatter')
          p <- add_trace(p, data = mtcars, 
                      x = mtcars[['mpg']], 
                      y = mtcars[['disp']],
                      z = mtcars[['cyl']],
                      type = 'scatter3d', 
                      mode = 'markers',
                      marker = list(size = 2)) 

      p <- layout(p, autosize = F, width = 500, height = 500,
                  scene = list(yaxis = list(type="log",
                                            zeroline=F, showline=T, 
                                            ticks="outside",
                                            tickvals=tval,
                                            ticktext=ttxt),
                               xaxis = list(type="log",
                                            zeroline=F, showline=T, 
                                            ticks="outside",
                                            tickvals=tval,
                                            ticktext=ttxt),
                               zaxis = list(type="log",
                                            zeroline=F, showline=T, 
                                            ticks="outside",
                                            tickvals=tval,
                                            ticktext=ttxt),
                               camera = list(eye = list(x = -1.5, y = 1.5, z = 1.5))))
    })
  }
    )
```

**for a 2D solution:**

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage( plotlyOutput('plot') ),

  server = function(input, output) {
    output$plot <- renderPlotly ({

      mtcars <- rbind(mtcars, mtcars*1000, mtcars/1000)  #create data with big logarithmic range
      maxlog <- round(log10(max(mtcars[['mpg']][mtcars[['mpg']]>0], mtcars[['disp']][mtcars[['disp']]>0])), digits = 0) +1 # determine max log needed
      minlog <- round(log10(min(mtcars[['mpg']][mtcars[['mpg']]>0], mtcars[['disp']][mtcars[['disp']]>0])), digits = 0) -1 # determine min log needed
      logrange <- (maxlog - minlog)*9 +1 # get the distance between smallest and largest log power
      tval <- sort(as.vector(sapply(seq(1,9), function(x) x*10^seq(minlog, maxlog)))) #generates a sequence of numbers in logarithmic divisions
      ttxt <- rep("",length(tval))  # no label at most of the ticks
      ttxt[seq(1,logrange,9)] <- formatC(tval, format = "e", digits = 2)[seq(1,logrange,9)] # every 9th tick is labelled


      p <- plot_ly(source = 'ThresholdScatter')
      p <- add_trace(p, data = mtcars, 
                     x = mtcars[['mpg']], 
                     y = mtcars[['disp']],
                     type = 'scatter', 
                     mode = 'markers',
                     marker = list(size = 2)) 

      p <- layout(p,autosize = F, width = 500, height = 500,
                  yaxis = list(type="log",
                                 zeroline=F, showline=T, 
                                 ticks="outside",
                                 tickvals=tval,
                                 ticktext=ttxt),
                  xaxis = list(type="log",
                               zeroline=F, showline=T, 
                               ticks="outside",
                               tickvals=tval,
                               ticktext=ttxt))
    })
  }
)
```

[image]