# Plotly axis as exponential format

Tags: javascript, r, plotly, subplot

This is a follow up on this question: [SO Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49626679/plotly-scientific-annotation-for-ticks-and-tick-number-not-as-wanted/49797567#49797567)

The answer in the above question uses JavaScript code that turns an axis ticks into exponential. It works for a single axis on a single plot.

When running it in a subplot() structure, it only works on the first plot when I apply it to the final plot.

The modification I am looking for are these:

1: How to make it work on subplots. I tried calling JavaScript in the build of each subplot, but all plots came out without exponential then.

2: make it work for both x an y axis (I tried, failed and cried a little)

3: Make it not destroy the universe when the axis turns out to not be a numerical (My app can plot date columns too, so it needs to check whether it actually is a numerical input)

4: If possible print as 1.23E+1 rather than 1E+1

```
 library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(htmlwidgets)


ui <- fluidPage(
    mainPanel(
     plotlyOutput('myplotly')
     )
  )

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  javascript <- "
function(el, x) 
{
  function fix_ticks()
  {
    ticks = Plotly.d3.selectAll('g.ytick').selectAll('text');
    ticks.forEach(function(tick) 
    {
      var num = parseInt(tick[0].innerHTML); 
      tick[0].innerHTML = num.toExponential();
    })
  }
  el.on('plotly_afterplot', fix_ticks);
}"


  output$myplotly <- renderPlotly({

    myplots <- lapply(unique(mtcars$cyl), function(v) {

    data <- mtcars[which(mtcars$cyl == v), ] 
      subp <-   plot_ly(data = data,
                x = rownames(data), 
                y = ~mpg,
                type = "bar")
      subp
     })

    p <- subplot(myplots, margin = 0.08)

    p$elementId <- NULL   ## to surpress warning of widgetid
    p <- onRender(p, javascript)

    p <- p %>% layout(margin =list(l = 60, r = 20, b = 160, t = 70) )

    p
  })
 }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**UPDATE**
with the answer suggestions given here I am now running the following code that checks for numerical and then works for each axis. I haven't been able to get the last suggestion to deal with negative values to work yet, which was using tick[0].innerHTML. I ended up using the suggestion under the answer under point 1, using, as I could not get the tick[0].innerHTML approach to work inside the forEach loop. However, the suggestion in response to earlier comment is going back to the tick[0] approach, and I can't get one approach to work completely.

This is the code I ended up using before running into negative -> NaN problems

```
  javascriptMPP <- "
  function(el, x) 
  {
    function isNumber(n) {
      return (Object.prototype.toString.call(n) === '[object Number]' || Object.prototype.toString.call(n) === '[object String]') &&!isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n.toString().replace(/^-/, ''));
    }
    function fixTicks()
    {
      ticks = Plotly.d3.selectAll('g.yaxislayer-above,g.xaxislayer-above').selectAll('text');
      ticks.each(function(d) 
      {
        if(parseInt(d.text) !== 0 )
        {
          var num = parseInt(d.text).toExponential(2);
          Plotly.d3.select(this).text(num);
        }
      })
    }
    el.on('plotly_afterplot', fixTicks);
  }"
```

Comment: Take care in spelling JavaScript correctly to avoid search collision with Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1: How to make it work on subplots. I tried calling java in the build
>   of each subplot, but all plots came out without exponential then.

The ticks of the 2nd/3rd/etc. subplot have class names like `y2tick`/`y3tick`/etc. We could make our d3 selector less specific and then use `each` to change all ticks.

```
ticks = Plotly.d3.selectAll('g.yaxislayer-above').selectAll('text');
ticks.each(function(d, i) 
{
  var num = parseInt(d.text).toExponential();
  Plotly.d3.select(this).text(num);
})
```

> 2: make it work for both x an y axis (I tried, failed and cried a
>   little)

Just change the selectAll statement to `Plotly.d3.selectAll('g.xaxislayer-above').selectAll('text')`

> 3: Make it not destroy the universe when the axis turns out to not be
>   a numerical (My app can plot date columns too, so it needs to check
>   whether it actually is a numerical input)

You could change your `fixTicks` functions to check if the input value is numeric, e.g. by using `typeof` or a regex. With values like 1999, 2000, etc. it might be tricky and you would need to manually address it.

> 4: If possible print as 1.23E+1 rather than 1E+1

`toExponential` takes one [parameter](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toexponential.asp) which is the "number of digits in the notation after the decimal point", i.e. `num.toExponential(3)` would do the trick in your case.

> From the comment: I seem to get NaN when the values on the ticks are negative values

Plotly uses an [Unicode minus sign](http://www.charbase.com/2212-unicode-minus-sign) instead of a regular dash. You can replace it with the following JavaScript line:

```
var num = parseInt(tick[0].innerHTML.replace(/\\u2013|\\u2014|\\u2212/g, '-'));
```

Note: the double backslash `\\` is required in R, pure JavaScript would require only a single `\`.

Comment: hm i'm almost there. Found a way to check for numerical in javascript, and set the format toExponential(2) gives two decimals. 
Trying this inside the javascript, but the concat stops it from working
  var ticksx = Plotly.d3.selectAll('g.xaxislayer-above').selectAll('text');
  var ticksy = Plotly.d3.selectAll('g.yaxislayer-above').selectAll('text');
  ticks = ticksy.concat(ticksx);
  ticks.each(function(d, i)
Without  concat, I can apply it now to X OR Y

Comment: Max, I seem to get NaN when the values on the ticks are negative values

Comment: Hm you seem to switch between the  tick[0].innerHTML approach and parseInt(d.text in the answers on my 2 questions.
I ended up using your   var num = parseInt(d.text).toExponential(2);
          Plotly.d3.select(this).text(num); solution, but I tried a few varieties likes this: var num parseInt(d.text).replace(/\\u2013|\\u2014|\\u2212/g, '-'));         
 var num = num.toExponential(2);
          Plotly.d3.select(this).text(num); 
but I can't seem to get the syntax right

Comment: Max, I think we have another problem with your solution. Plotly puts labels in like 10k, 20k etc, and your script (logically) makes those into 1.00E1 and 2,00E1

Comment: The horror! I'll look at it when I'm back a usable computer.

Comment: Max, found our old discussion here and gave it another shot. I managed to get this one working now, see answer below. It does however NOT work for log scale.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally managed to solve all issues thanks to the other answer posted here.

javascript:
 replaces symbols so that it works too for negative values

```
  var num1 = parseInt(d.text.replace(/\\u2013|\\u2014|\\u2212/g, '-'));
```

skips if value is 0 as it doesnt have to be changed to exp format

```
   if(parseInt(d.text) !== 0 )
```

skips if values are text (after changing the symbol for negatives, otherwise they are seen as text

```
 if(isNaN(num1)){
```

Also added the layout command to the plot code, and put the labels on the x axis at a 45 degrees angle, otherwise they will overlap each other. 
Some changes to the mtcars df are made so that we get negative and large numbers in the data.

For plotting text values on the xaxis it works with this:

```
x = rownames(data),
```

instead of a numerical x parameter

```
x = ~disp,
```

Here is the working code:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(htmlwidgets)


ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    plotlyOutput('myplotly')
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  javascriptMPP <- "
  function(el, x) 
  {
  function isNumber(n) {
  return (Object.prototype.toString.call(n) === '[object Number]' || Object.prototype.toString.call(n) === '[object String]') &&!isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n.toString().replace(/^-/, ''));
  }
  function fixTicks()
  {
  ticks = Plotly.d3.selectAll('g.yaxislayer-above,g.xaxislayer-above').selectAll('text');
  ticks.each(function(d) 
  {
   if(parseInt(d.text) !== 0 )
  {
  var num1 = parseInt(d.text.replace(/\\u2013|\\u2014|\\u2212/g, '-'));
  if(isNaN(num1)){
  } else {
    var num = parseInt(num1).toExponential(2);
  Plotly.d3.select(this).text(num);
  }
}
  })
  }
  el.on('plotly_afterplot', fixTicks);
  }"

  output$myplotly <- renderPlotly({
    mtcars2 <- mtcars
    mtcars2$mpg <- mtcars2$mpg*-1
    mtcars <- rbind(mtcars, mtcars2)
    mtcars3 <- mtcars
    mtcars3$mpg <- mtcars3$mpg*1000000

    mtcars <- rbind(mtcars, mtcars3)

    myplots <- lapply(unique(mtcars$cyl), function(v) {

      data <- mtcars[which(mtcars$cyl == v), ] 
      subp <-   plot_ly(data = data,
                        x = ~disp, 
                        y = ~mpg,
                        type = "bar")
      subp <- layout(subp, xaxis = list(tickangle = 45))
      subp
    })

    p <- subplot(myplots, margin = 0.08)

    p$elementId <- NULL   ## to surpress warning of widgetid
    p <- onRender(p, javascriptMPP)

    p <- p %>% layout(margin =list(l = 60, r = 20, b = 160, t = 70) )

    p
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```