# How to have un-even tick value for color-bar in plotly

Tags: javascript, plot, plotly, plotly.js

In plotly how can I render this type of color-bar for the contour plot? Just trying to figure out if the contour support un-even tick value for color-bar of the contour plot.

[image]

The image above is what I am looking for to get within plotly.

The `tickvals` and `ticktext` does not work as expected.

Answer (score 3):

Try this Stackoverflow Question:

[Plotly axis as exponential format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49818203/plotly-axis-as-exponential-format)

Direct Text-Form: ALL CREDIT TO: @MaximilianPeters

> 1: How to make it work on subplots. I tried calling java in the build
>   of each subplot, but all plots came out without exponential then.

The ticks of the 2nd/3rd/etc. subplot have class names like `y2tick`/`y3tick`/etc. We could make our d3 selector less specific and then use `each` to change all ticks.

```
ticks = Plotly.d3.selectAll('g.yaxislayer-above').selectAll('text');
ticks.each(function(d, i) 
{
  var num = parseInt(d.text).toExponential();
  Plotly.d3.select(this).text(num);
})
```

> 2: make it work for both x an y axis (I tried, failed and cried a
>   little)

Just change the selectAll statement to `Plotly.d3.selectAll('g.xaxislayer-above').selectAll('text')`

> 3: Make it not destroy the universe when the axis turns out to not be
>   a numerical (My app can plot date columns too, so it needs to check
>   whether it actually is a numerical input)

You could change your `fixTicks` functions to check if the input value is numeric, e.g. by using `typeof` or a regex. With values like 1999, 2000, etc. it might be tricky and you would need to manually address it.

> 4: If possible print as 1.23E+1 rather than 1E+1

`toExponential` takes one [parameter](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toexponential.asp) which is the "number of digits in the notation after the decimal point", i.e. `num.toExponential(3)` would do the trick in your case.

> From the comment: I seem to get NaN when the values on the ticks are negative values

Plotly uses an [Unicode minus sign](http://www.charbase.com/2212-unicode-minus-sign) instead of a regular dash. You can replace it with the following JavaScript line:

```
var num = parseInt(tick[0].innerHTML.replace(/\\u2013|\\u2014|\\u2212/g, '-'));
```

Note: the double backslash `\\` is required in R, pure JavaScript would require only a single `\`.

Comment: When changing the values will this reflect the values within the plot or does this only change the text of the color bar? Havent tried it yet since I am not in my place right now.

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin Honestly, I don't know. You'll need to test that :/ Sorry.

Comment: This does not actually reflect the colors of the color-bar within the contour plot. So when the above solution is executed it only changes the values of the color bar which you can already do within the library.