# Adding extra gridlines to bar chart doubles the names of the legend

Tags: r, plotly

I create the bar chart below in which I add `gridlines` between the main `gridlines`. The issue is that this new `trace` doubles the names of my `legend` which I do not want to.

```
co<-c("AL","FG","GH","HJ","FT")
va<-c(1000000,1000000,1000000,5000000,5000000)
cova<-data.frame(co,va)
mtick <- 2*10**5 # minor ticks every 200k
library(plotly)
library(comprehenr)
    
    fig1 <- plot_ly(cova, x = ~co, y = ~va,
                    type = 'bar',
                    hovertemplate = paste('%{x}', '<br>Deaths: %{y}<br><extra></extra>'),
                    colors = c("#60ab3d","#6bbabf","#c4d436","#3e5b84","#028c75"),
                    color = ~co
                    
                    
                    
    ) 
    fig1 <- fig1 %>% layout(showlegend = TRUE,title=list(text="worldwide,by selected territories and period",x = 0,y=1,font=list(size=10)),
                            font = list(color = '#a2a2a2'),
                            legend=list(title=list(text='<b> Top 5 </b>'),itemclick = F, itemdoubleclick = F,orientation="h",xanchor = "center",x = 0,y=1.1),
                            
                            yaxis = list(fixedrange = TRUE,title="",
                                         #dtick = 250000
                                         showgrid = T,gridcolor = "#a2a2a2", showline = FALSE, showticklabels = TRUE, domain= c(0, 0.85)),
                            xaxis = list(fixedrange = TRUE,title="",zeroline = FALSE, showline = T,showticklabels = F,tickangle=45, showgrid = FALSE))%>% 
      
      config(modeBarButtonsToRemove = c('toImage',"zoom2d","toggleSpikelines","hoverClosestCartesian","hoverCompareCartesian","drawline","autoScale2d" ,"resetScale2d","zoomIn2d","zoomOut2d","pan2d",'select2d','lasso2d'))%>%
      config(displaylogo = FALSE)
    fig1%>% add_trace(x=~co, y=~va, yaxis="y2", marker=list(color='rgba(0,0,0,0)')) %>%
      layout(yaxis2=list( overlaying="y", 
                          tickvals=to_list(for(i in seq(0, max(cova$va), by=mtick) )  if (i%%10**4) i ), 
                          showticklabels=FALSE ,showlegend=F))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `showlegend=F` in `add_trace` -

```
fig1 %>% 
  add_trace(x=~co, y=~va, yaxis="y2", showlegend=F) %>%
  layout(yaxis2=list( overlaying="y", 
                      tickvals=to_list(for(i in seq(0, max(cova$va), by=mtick) )  if (i%%10**4) i ), 
                      showticklabels=FALSE ,showlegend=F))
```

[image]