# Add specific number of gridlines between main gridlines in a dynamic chart

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I have the shiny app below in which my main goal is to add 4 lighter in color `gridlines` between the main `gridlines` as in the default chart. The issue is that the countries (`co`) displayed in the chart are dynamic (up to 5) and their values (`va`) have a wide range so I would like a generic way to have every time 4 lighter gridlines between the main gridlines of the bar.

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(shinydashboard)
library(comprehenr)
library(shinyWidgets)
co<-c("AL","FG","GH","HJ","FT","BR","CHE","FR","HU","FGJ")
va<-c(1000000,1000000,1000000,5000000,5000000,1000,450,4567,10,35000)
cova<-data.frame(co,va)
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    
    pickerInput(
      inputId = "c2",
      label = "",
      choices = cova$co,
      multiple = TRUE,
      selected=c("AL","FG","GH","HJ","FT"),
      options = pickerOptions(`actions-box` = TRUE,
                              title = "Countries/territories",
                              selectedTextFormat = 'static',
                              "max-options" = 5,
                              "max-options-text" = "No more!"
      )
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    
 plotlyOutput("plot",height = 600)
      
    )
  )


server <- function(input, output) { 
  
  
  
  output$plot<-renderPlotly({
    cova<-subset(cova,co %in% input$c2)
    fig1 <- plot_ly(cova, x = ~co, y = ~va,
                   type = 'bar'
    ) 
    fig1 <- fig1%>% layout(showlegend=F,
                           font = list(color = '#a2a2a2'),
                           yaxis = list(title="", showgrid = T,gridcolor = "#a2a2a2", showline = FALSE, showticklabels = TRUE, 
                                        domain= c(0, 0.85)),
                           xaxis = list(title="",zeroline = FALSE, showline = T,showticklabels = F,tickangle=45, showgrid = FALSE))
    
    # plot additional transpareent bar on top of original bar
    # give this "invisible" layer a different y-axis with ticks which are minor ticks
    # this then generates gridlines,  that can be styles as you please
    # NB - tickvals excludes major tickval using integer remainder logic in list comprehension
    mtick <- 2*10**5 # minor ticks every 200k
    fig1 %>% add_trace(x=~co, y=~va, yaxis="y2", marker=list(color='rgba(0,0,0,0)')) %>%
      layout(yaxis2=list( overlaying="y", 
                          tickvals=to_list(for(i in seq(0, max(cova$va), by=mtick) )  if (i%%10**6) i ), 
                          showticklabels=FALSE ))
    
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```